# Yii global date format (l18n)

Tags: date, yii, internationalization, format

When I type:

```
Yii::app()->getLocale()->dateFormat
```

it gives me the correct dateformat for the current set language. (in my example it is 'de' => dd.MM.yyyy). But when I type:

```
Yii::app()->format->dateFormat
```

Yii gives me the date format for 'en_us' (Y/m/d).

With getLocale() I will get only the string saved in i18n file. In ->format->date() this format string should be used, but I don't find a way to assign the i18n string to the CDateFormatter or CFormatter Object.

Answer (score 1):

The [`CFormatter`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormatter) component accessed with `Yii::app()->format` is not meant to be used for localization out of the box; it does not automatically work according to the application locale.

You could manually change the relevant properties on `Yii::app()->format` to bring it in line with the application locale, but there is a more convenient way to format dates:

```
Yii::app()->locale->dateFormatter->formatDateTime(...)
```

See [`CDateFormatter::formatDateTime`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter#formatDateTime-detail) for more information; if you want more control, there are other methods such as [`CDateFormatter::format`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter#format-detail) available. Also keep in mind that [`CLocale::getNumberFormatter()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLocale#getNumberFormatter-detail) is available to format numbers.